# Area of metric spheres in Riemannian manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, integration

I am trying to estimate the integral $\int \mathbb{e} ^{-d(x_0,x)^2} \mathbb{d}x$ on a Riemann manifold $(M,g)$, for some arbitrary fixed $x_0 \in M$ and $d$ the usual distance. The only thing that I can think of is to use some coarea theorem, leading to $\int _0 ^\infty \mathbb{e} ^{-r^2} A(x_0, r) \mathbb{d}r$, where $A(x_0, r)$ is the area of the metric sphere of center $x_0$ and radius $r$. The issue now is to have some estimate of $A$. Surprisingly, even though there are plenty of comparison theorems for the volume of metric balls, I haven't been able to find anything usable on the area of spheres. Therefore, the questions:

- how would you approach this integral (if not by the coarea formula)?
- is it finite? (I assume so)
- is $A$ a polynomial in $r$ (of degree $n-1$)? If so, I would expect it not to have a free term, but what about its leading coefficient?
- can $A$ be computed explicitly in space forms (other than Euclidian, of course)?
- are there comparison theorems for $A$?

Thank you.

Comment: A possible approach: If $\exp_{x_0}$ is a bijection $T_{x_0}M\to M$, then you can turn your integral into some integral over the tangent space (or get an estimate if it is not bijective). You have $d(x_0,\exp_{x_0}v)^2\leq|v|^2$ (with equality if $\exp$ is injective) for $v\in T_{x_0}M$, so you have a Gaussian integral in a Euclidean space with weight coming from pulling the metric to the tangent space.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: My manifold is not necessarily complete, so $\mathbb{exp _{x_0} }$ cannot even be defined on the whole $T _{x_0} M$.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: The inequality that you suggest would make my integral "greater or equal" than some Gaussian integral, while I'm looking to (hopefully) get "less or equal".

Comment: I guess my method would work if $\exp_{x_0}$ is bijective on its maximal domain of definition (which need not be the entire tangent space). If you don't want to assume this much, this approach might be useless.

Comment: It seems like things could go quite badly if your manifold is not complete, even in constant curvature. Puncture a round 2-sphere at antipodal points and take its universal cover. Now as $x_0$ heads towards one of the missing points, $A$ grows without bound.

Comment: Have you tried the special case when $M=\mathbb{R}^n$, $x_0=0$, and the metric $g$ is conformal to the Euclidean metric?

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu: No, I haven't. Would it teach me anything useful?

Comment: @AlexM  This example alone  shows the massive variability built in the problem. It reminds me of a Heisenberg dictum: one can say almost everything  about nothing, and almost nothing about everything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The integral might be infinite.
Indeed, the function $A(r)$ can grow as fast as you want, but in this case  the Ricci curvature in some of the radial direction have to go to $-\infty$ as $r\to\infty$. (Needless to say $A$ can grow faster than any polynomial.)

If Ricci curvature is bounded below then $A(r)$ has at most exponential growth --- this follows from the Bishop--Gromov inequality. In this case you integral has to be finite.

Comment: P.S. if $n=\dim M$ and $\mathrm{Ric}_M\ge -(n-1)$ then Bishop--Gromov inequality says that the function $$r\mapsto A(r)/(\sinh r)^{n-1}$$ is nonincreasing.

Comment: Let me come back to your answer, please. You assume lower-boundedness of the Ricci curvature, but not completeness. All the proofs of Bishop-Gromov that I have read require completeness. Do you know of any version of it without this requirement? (I had asked [a related question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/217832/the-completeness-assumption-in-some-comparison-theorems-in-riemannian-geometry) a few days ago, and only now did I remember your answer.)

Comment: @AlexM. One needs completeness, without one you can do pretty much anything, in particular there is no Bishop--Gromov.

Answer (score 6):

I personally do not think that you can compute that integral explicitly in general just because the geodesic spheres could become quite ugly. $\newcommand{\bx}{\boldsymbol{x}}$ However, when $M$ has finite volume,  you can obtain   pretty good asymptotic estimates for the integral

$$ I(\lambda,\bx_0)=\int_M  e^{-\lambda d(\bx_0,\bx)^2}  dV_g(x), $$

as $\lambda\to \infty$. To obtain these  asymptotic estimates  you write  $dV_g(\bx)$ in normal coordinates $(t^1,\dotsc, t^n)$  at $\bx_0$ in the form

$$ dV_g(x) = \rho(t) dt^1\wedge\cdots \wedge dt^n. $$

The  Taylor  expansion of $\rho(t)$ at $t=0$  can be described explicitly in terms  of geometric invariants at $\bx_0$.    The  degree 4 Taylor polynomial of $\rho$ at $t=0$ is described in   Corollary 9.9 of A. Gray's book *Tubes*, 2nd Edition, Birhauser, 2006.   The Taylor  polynomials of degree $>4$ are  very complicated.

The integral you  are interested  could be computed on  spaces  with rich symmetries, but even in those cases it is not easy.

Comment: Agreed, but normal coordinates cover only a small patch of the whole manifold. What am I going to do with the rest? (And no, I do not hope for an explicit result, just for a "sharp" estimate.)

Comment: In any case, this makes me think of the formula of steepest descent in Euclidean spaces. Does a similar thing exist for Riemannian manifolds? With Google I can only find articles about optimizations.

Comment: @AlexM. If the injectivity radius at $x_0$ is small  then there is very little you can do. However, if you allow for the large parameter $\lambda$, anything that is outside    a small geodesic ball is negligible for large $\lambda$.

Answer (score 2):

You could integrate the co-area formula by parts, to get:
$$\int_0^\infty 2re^{-r^2}V(x_0,r)dr$$
where $V(x_0,r)$ is the volume of the ball at $x_0$ of radius $r$, and then use comparison results for $V$.

Comment: Yes, I realised this after having posted the question. Still, I'm not sure whether this helps: are explicit formulae for the volume of metric balls in space forms known? Or, at least, is $V(x_0, r)$ a polynomial function of $r$?

Comment: My point is just that you can use comparison results for $V$ in place of comparison results for $A$.  As for evaluating your integral explicitly, the integration by parts I mention is probably not very helpful.

Comment: @AlexM.:  $V(x_0,r)$ is not generally polynomial in $r$ in non-flat space forms.  For example, on the $2$-sphere with Gauss curvature $K\equiv 1$, one finds $$V(x_0,r) = 2\pi \,(1{-}\cos r), \qquad 0\le r\le \pi.$$  The general formula involves polynomials in trig (or hyperbolic trig) functions.

Comment: @RobertBryant: I am very interested in the general formula for space forms (at least for small balls). Do you know where I could find it?

Comment: I don't know a reference off the top of my head, but straightforward calculation shows that $$V(x_0,r) = V_{n-1}\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^\ell}{2^{n-1}(\sqrt{-K})^n}{{n{-}1}\choose{\ell}}{{\bigl({e}^{(n-1-2\ell)\sqrt{-K}\,r}-1\bigr)}\over{(n-1-2\ell)}}$$ when $M$ is an $n$-dimensional space form of sectional curvature $K\not=0$ and $V_{n-1}$ is the volume of the unit $(n{-}1)$-sphere in Euclidean $n$-space.  (Note that, even when $K>0$, this is a real-valued function with leading order term $V_{n-1}r^n/n$.) Perhaps this formula simplifies?

Comment: Actually, I just realized that the above formula doesn't quite work when $n$ is odd, only when $n$ is even.  In the case of $n$ odd, one must (obviously) omit the term with $\ell = (n-1)/2$ and replace it with the appropriate linear term in $r$.  If you need this spelled out, let me know and I can explain.

Comment: @RobertBryant: Let me take my chances: if $K<0$, then $A(r)=\frac{2 {\pi}^{\frac n 2}}{\Gamma (\frac n 2)} \frac 1 {\sqrt {-K}}^{n-1} (\sinh \sqrt {-K} r)^{n-1}$; if $K>0$ change $-K$ into $K$ and $\sinh$ into $\sin$ in the above formula. $A(r)$ is the area of the metric ball of radius $r$. You get the volume by integrating it. The coefficient with $\Gamma$ is the measure of ${\Bbb S}^{n-1}$. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, that should be right.  I merely did the integration, since you said you wanted the explicit formula for the volume.